# How to add new columns into pandas Series based on existing column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas Series:
`output={'index':[0,1,2,3,4],'output'=[0,1,0,0,1]}`

I would like to split output column into 2 columns '0' and '1':

```
index output 0 1
0     0      1 0
1     1      0 1
2     0      1 0
3     0      1 0
4     1      0 1
```

then, I would like to delete output column, and be left only with 3 columns: index, 0 and 1

I tried this ugly code:

```
for i in output:
    if i==0:
        output['0'],ouput['1']=1,0
    else:
        output['0'],ouput['1']=0,1
```

But it only added 2 row at the end of my Series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `DataFrame` constructor and broadcasting boolean mask:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,1,2,3,4],'output':[0,1,0,0,1]})

output[['0','1']]=pd.DataFrame(np.where((output['output'] == 0).values[:, None], [1,0], [0,1]))
print (output)
   index  output  0  1
0      0       0  1  0
1      1       1  0  1
2      2       0  1  0
3      3       0  1  0
4      4       1  0  1
```

If input is `Series` first create `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,1,2,3,4],'output':[0,1,0,0,1]}).set_index('index')['output']
print (s)
index
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    1
Name: output, dtype: int64

df = s.to_frame()
df[['0','1']] = pd.DataFrame(np.where((s == 0).values[:, None], [1,0], [0,1]))
print (df)
       output  0  1
index              
0           0  1  0
1           1  0  1
2           0  1  0
3           0  1  0
4           1  0  1
```

Comment: so I must convert my Series into Dataframe first?

Comment: @SimpleEngineer - Yes, exactly.

Comment: ok, becaus eI tried to apply as it is, and python said it couldn't find the column 'output'

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this is what you want:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({"0": (output == 0), "1": (output != 0)}, dtype=int)
```

If the output series contains only `0` and `1`, you can simply do

```
result = pd.DataFrame({"0": 1 - output, "1": output})
```

Comment: thank a lot... this solution is also very elegant... but then I have to create and remove result DataFrame... or maybe I will just over right output Pandas Series

Comment: You just override the `output` variable if you don't need the pandas Series any more.